# Node.js Event and functions

Tags: node.js, function, events

I have been learning node.js and I am confused with some thing here:

this:

```
home.lights.on('on', function(number, room) {  
    console.log('light number %d in room %s was turned on', number, room);
});
```

and this:

```
function lightsOn(number, room){
    console.log('light number %d in room %s was turned on', number, room);
}
lightsOn(1,2);
```

do the same thing or they have difference between them?

Comment: The function `.on()` is usually used for creating an event hander (generaly, the first parameter is the event name/type, and the second is the callback). So on your first snippet, you create an event handler. On your second, you create a function and call it. But it depends on what `home.lights` is.

Comment: and what is the diff between calling home.lights.emit() and lightsOn?

Comment: If you use the events, you can have multiple handlers. Also, events are asynchronous, which is better in most cases.

Comment: so using events better than just calling the functions?

Comment: In most cases, yes. But you can still use the single function. It depends on your whole app.

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful